# Automatic translation with different domains per languages?

Tags: translation

I would like to know if there is a plugin to make automatic translations with one different domain by language for the same project. For example :

car.co.uk for the English

voiture.fr for the French

coche.es for the Spanish

etc.

And still have an automatic translation : If I create a new article in French on voiture.fr, there also an automatic creation and translation on the English version (car.co.uk) and on the Spanish version (coche.es) without any human actions?

I know I can’t do this with Weglot (only one domain) so I’m searching an alternative…

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do this with WPML. Keep in mind that it's a paid add-on and I have not tested it myself. Check out their page here: https://wpml.org/documentation/automatic-translation/

Comment: Thanks I'm going to check that, thx! It's ok if it's not free ;)